# How to bring a win form to front?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform that drives me crazy...
When I open it, it opens and goes behind the main form from which I open it.
I tried calling: BringToFront(), Focus(), Activacte() and still nothing....
Here is my code:

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
frm.Show();
frm.BringToFront();
frm.Activate();
```

I know that the main form has the TopMost property set to true, but I also have this code that works just fine:

```
Form frmLog = new Form();
LogViewer logControl = new LogViewer();
frmLog.Controls.Add(logControl);
logControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frmLog.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frmLog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
frmLog.Text = "Log Viewer";
frmLog.Show();
```

So that is way it drives me crazy...

Comment: Make sure the TopMost property of your parent form is not set to true.

Comment: It is set to true, but still I have a user control that I load to a new form that I create and it opens fine like this: `Form frmLog = new Form();
                                LogViewer logControl = new LogViewer();
                                frmLog.Controls.Add(logControl);
                                logControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                                frmLog.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                                frmLog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                                frmLog.Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the instance of the main form to the `Show` method of the form you want to show.

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.Show(this);
```

Of course this works if you are instanciating the second form inside the main form class (so you can use the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your main form as owner for `frm` by using [Form.Show(IWin32Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd) method.

So your code should look like

```
frm.Show(this);
```